# Stack InvalidRelFile error when adding local package

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm having this strange issue : I'm trying to add a local package to my stack file and I get the following error. when I try to build it (`stack build`) it kind of work but fails suggesting me to use `stack solver` but when I run `stack solver` I got the following error

```
Using configuration file: stack.yaml
InvalidRelFile "/home/max/devel/sql-fragment/sql-fragment.cabal"
```

My stack file looks like

```
flags: {}
packages:
- '.'
- ../sql-fragment
extra-deps:
   ...
```

I'm on Ubuntu 15.02 trying to use GHC-7.8.4 and stack 1.0.4
The two packages, [sql-fragment](http://github.com/maxigit/sql-fragment.git) and [sql-fragment-mysql-simple](https://github.com/maxigit/sql-fragment-mysql-simple.git) can be found on github.

Comment: well does the `sql-fragment` package itself build ... is the cabal-file ok?

Comment: @Carsten it builds, so I guess the cabal-file is ok.

Comment: Try move `../sql-fragment` into your project root and change the path to `sql-fragment`. `..` in `stack.yaml` sometimes causes issues I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a bug in stack. I managed to find a workaround by moving `sql-fragment` directory into `sql-fragment-mysql-simple`, change `../sql-fragment` to `sql-fragment` in the stack file launch the solver -`stack solver --update-config` and it works. What is strange is, I add to properly move the directory to make it work (just creating a symbolic link woudn't work) and once the solver has done its job. I moved  `sql-fragment` where it was, revert the path to `../sql-fragment` and `stack build` works perfectly ;-).

Comment: This is pretty ridiculous, but works! Thanks a lot. Did you open a bug on stack for that?

Comment: I did. I understand why the symbolic link didn't work. It's because stack follows the symbolic link instead of just trusting me ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with this commit. https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/commit/42a61fb278aeb99ad61bb088da9a87b2313ac325

The issue tracker is a better place for this.